# Continuity of linear interpolation function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I'm trying to do this exercise, but I got stuck. The text is:

Let K be a closed subset of [0,1] containing 0 and 1, and let $f$ be a continuous real-valued function on K. Extend $f$ to [0,1] by linear interpolation: if $
x \in [0,1]/K $ let $l = sup\{k \in K: k < x\}$, let $r = inf\{k \in K: k > x\}$, and let:

$$
f(x) = \frac{(r-x)}{(r-l)}f(l)+\frac{(x-l)}{(r-l)}f(r)
$$

Show that the extended real-valued function $f$ is continuous on [0,1]

Now, we know that $f$ is continuous on K and that the product of continuous function is continuous. So I tried to prove that the functions:

$$
y(x) = \frac{(r-x)}{(r-l)} 
$$
$$
z(x) = \frac{(x-l)}{(r-l)} 
$$
Is continuous on $\Re$, but I'm not so sure this is the right way to solve the exercise. Any help would be greatly apreciated!

Comment: r and l belong to [0, 1]. Hence, it remains continuous in the interval.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I'm not so sure that this is right though... r and l belong to a closed subset of [0,1], which may be not an interval! We only know that K contains the points {0} and {1} and the sets [0], [1] are closed, so their union is closed (K is closed), but it's not an interval